# Saving a memory address in a variable

Tags: microcontroller, c++

1. If I initialize a variable (in the SRAM), can it happen that its location/position in memory changes each time I simulate or add other variables to the program? Or will it always remain in that location? (if I don't change it manually of course)
2. Is it possible to save within a variable `a` the memory address in which another variable `b` is stored. Which function can I use?

Thanks!

(I am working on STM32CubeIDE)

Comment: The answer depends on how you declare your variable. Please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a C++ programming question.

> If I initialize a variable (in the SRAM), can it happen that its location/position in memory changes each time I simulate or add other variables to the program?

Yes. Most likely if you add variables (well, it depends whether the new variable is before or after the one you are asking about). Note that the compiler doesn't have to put the variables in the order you say - except inside a `struct` or `class`.

> Is it possible to save within a variable a the memory address in which another variable b is stored. Which function can I use?

Yes, this is a basic feature of C and C++ called "pointers". A variable that holds the address of an `int` should be declared as `int*`. Putting `&` in front of a variable names calculates its address. And `*` in front means to access that address.

e.g.

```
int a;
int* address_of_a; // or int *address_of_a; (they mean the same thing)
address_of_a = &a; // the variable address_of_a has the number which is the address of the variable a
*address_of_a = 5;
// now the variable a has the number 5
```

Of course, a full explanation of pointers is too long to write here.

---

A note: variable declaration syntax is a bit... weird. In the line `int* address_of_a;` the `*` applies to `address_of_a` and not to `int`. If you declare more than one variable in the same line you might not get what you thought:

```
int* a, b;
// a is int*
// b is int

// to make them both int* you could write:
int *a, *b;
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer. I tried what you said. I want to move the string "my_data_SRAM" from its memory address where it is initialised (I found it as you say) .. to the base address of the FLASH (written on the manual of the STM32F407 I am using). I wrote this code, but in the destination address (i.e. the base address of the FLASH) there is nothing, and I don't understand why it doesn't work. Do you know where I might have gone wrong? The code is in the next comment:

Comment: `char my_data_RAM[] = "I'm in RAM";
    char *pointer_my_data_RAM;
    pointer_my_data_RAM = &my_data_RAM;
    size_t address_my_data_RAM;
    address_my_data_RAM = (size_t)pointer_my_data_RAM;`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(my_data_RAM); i++) {
*((uint8_t *)BASE_ADDRESS_FLASH+i) = my_data_RAM[i];
}`

Comment: @KaleM I don't think you can write to flash like that. Usually flash needs some special sequence to write to it, and you can only write a whole bunch of bytes at once, not separate bytes.

Comment: @KaleM locating predefined data in flash is doable without writing during runtime but requires some fooling around with the linker, searching may find some answers, here’s a thread from the ST forums: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W000014wt4KSAQ/placing-string-in-a-fixed-memory-address-on-flash